# my HTML page refreshes after one, two or three iterations. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a blade stress routine all input fields should be numeric.

The Claculate button will calclate then sometimes refresh (you can see the table fill out coming from the  script) the refresh takes out the table answers and all the filled in values.

When it doesn't refresh I can then print the page or change values and hit calculate again. This is the intention of the HTML App.

Is there spmething that I don't know about browsers?

I have tried on Opera with debug on finish the whole Calc1() funtion then keep tracing goes to Opera code so hit F8 and it will sometimes work sometimes refresh the page. I have tried Chrome Firefox is not working propely on the computer will have to reload it.

Thank you for any feedback that can solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- turn on quirks mode for IE -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>MixPro&reg; BladeStress 3000 & 4000</title>    
    <style>
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 170px;
      }
      span {
          line-height: 1.0;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<div id="header" style="position: fixed;  top: 0;  left: 0;  width: 100%;  height: 10px;">
      <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;">
        <div style="width:25%; float:left; text-align:left;"><img src="/tracker/static/mixpro.jpg" alt="MixPro Logo"></div>
        <div style="width:50%; float: left; text-align:center; font-family: TeXGyreChorus; font-size: 35px;">
            <!-- <div><img src="/tracker/static/vortex.jpg" alt="Squirrel" style="float: left; height:110px;"></div>-->
          <div><bold><br>MixPro<sup>&reg;</sup> BladeStress 3000 & 4000</bold></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:25%; float: left; text-align:right;"><img src="/tracker/static/mixpro.jpg" alt="MixPro Logo"></div>
      </div>
</div>  
</section>
    <div style="border-style: double; margin-top:150px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; line-height: 1.7;" id='maindiv'>
        <form autocomplete="off" style="padding-left: 50px;">
            <label for="mpower">Motor Power:</label>
            <input type="text" id="mpower"><br>
            <label for="slurrySG">Slurry Specific Gravity:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slurrySG"><br>
            <label for="HSF">Hydraulic Service Factor:</label>
            <input type="text" id="HSF"><br>
            <label for="TF">Turbine Factor:</label>
            <input type="text" id="TF"><br>
            <label for="shdia">Shaft Diameter:</label>
            <input type="text" id="shdia"><br>
            <label for="hubdia">Hub Diameter:</label>
            <input type="text" id="hubdia"><br>
            <label for="ImpellerType">Impeller Type:</label>
            <select id="ImpellerType">
              <option value="3300">3300</option>
              <option value="3400">3400</option>
              <option value="4445">4445</option>
              <option value="4490">4490</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="pdia">Impeller Diameter:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pdia"><br>
            <label for="n">Output Speed:</label>
            <input type="text" id="n"><br>
            <label for="ConnectionType">Connection Type:</label>
            <select id="ConnectionType" onchange="ConnectionType1()">
              <option value="Bolted">Bolted</option>
              <option value="Welded">Welded</option>
            </select><br>
            <label id="learth" for="earth">Ear Thickness:</label>
            <input type="text" id="earth"><br id="bearth">
            <label for="bladeth">Blade Thickness:</label>
            <input type="text" id="bladeth"><br>
            Gusset:
                <label style="margin-left:117px;" class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" onchange="handleClick1();" name="radio1">Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input style="margin-left:-95px;" type="radio" onchange="handleClick2();" name="radio1">No
                </label>
            <br>
            <label style="display: none;" id="lgussth" for="gussth">Gusset Thickness:</label>
            <input style="display: none;" type="text" id="gussth" name="gussth"><br style="display: none;" id="bgussth">
            <label style="display: none;" id="lnguss" for="nguss">Number of Gussets:</label>
            <input style="display: none;" type="text" id="nguss" name="nguss"><br style="display: none;" id="bnguss">
            <button style="margin-left:170px; width:80px;" id="Calc" value="Calc" onclick="Calc1()">Calculate</button>
            <button style="width:80px;"id="Print" value="Print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
            <br>
            <table style="line-height: 1.2; width:65%;">
                <tr>
                    <th id="stresstitle" style="text-align:left"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="earstress1"></td>
                    <td id="earstress2" style="text-align:right"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="bladestress1"></td>
                    <td id="bladestress2" style="text-align:right"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="powerdraw1"></td>
                    <td id="powerdraw2" style="text-align:right"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th id="taper" style="text-align:left"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    
<script language='javascript'>
    var gusset = false;
    var bolted = true;
    var inputvalid = true;
    function handleClick1() {
        document.getElementById("lgussth").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("gussth").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("bgussth").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("lnguss").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("nguss").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("bnguss").style.display = "inline";
        gusset = true;
    }
    function handleClick2() {
        document.getElementById("lnguss").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("nguss").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("bnguss").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("lgussth").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gussth").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("bgussth").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gussth").value = null;
        document.getElementById("nguss").value = null;
        gusset = false;
    }
    function ConnectionType1() {
      var x = document.getElementById("ConnectionType").value;
      if (x == "Bolted") {
        document.getElementById("learth").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("earth").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("bearth").style.display = "inline";
        bolted = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("learth").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("earth").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("bearth").style.display = "none";
        bolted = false;
      }
    }
    function Calc1() {
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("mpower").value)) {
            alert("Motor Power Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("mpower").value == 0) {
                alert("Motor Power Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("slurrySG").value)) {
            alert("Slurry Specific Gravity Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("slurrySG").value == 0) {
                alert("Slurry Specific Gravity Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("HSF").value)) {
            alert("Hydraulic Service Factor Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("HSF").value == 0) {
                alert("Hydraulic Service Factor Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("TF").value)) {
            alert("Turbine Factor Must be a number");
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("TF").value == 0) {
                alert("Turbine Factor Must not be blank");
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("shdia").value)) {
            alert("Shaft Diameter Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("shdia").value == 0) {
                alert("Shaft Diameter Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("hubdia").value)) {
            alert("Hub Diameter Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("hubdia").value == 0) {
                alert("Hub Diameter Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("pdia").value)) {
            alert("Impeller Diameter Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("pdia").value == 0) {
                alert("Impeller Diameter Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("n").value)) {
            alert("Output Speed Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("n").value == 0) {
                alert("Output Speed Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (document.getElementById("ConnectionType").value == "Bolted") {
            if (isNaN(document.getElementById("earth").value)) {
                alert("Ear Thickness Must be a number");
                inputvalid = false;
            } else {
                if (document.getElementById("earth").value == 0) {
                    alert("Ear Thickness Must not be blank");
                    inputvalid = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("earth").value = "";
        }
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("bladeth").value)) {
            alert("Blade Thickness Must be a number");
            inputvalid = false;
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("bladeth").value == 0) {
                alert("Blade Thickness Must not be blank");
                inputvalid = false;
            }
        }
        if (gusset) {
            if (isNaN(document.getElementById("gussth").value)) {
                alert("Gusset Thickness Must be a number");
                inputvalid = false;
            } else {
                if (document.getElementById("gussth").value == 0) {
                    alert("Gusset Thickness Must not be blank");
                    inputvalid = false;
                }
            };
            if (isNaN(document.getElementById("nguss").value)) {
                alert("Number of Gussets Must be a number");
                inputvalid = false;
            } else {
                if (document.getElementById("nguss").value == 0) {
                    alert("Number of Gussets Must not be blank");
                    inputvalid = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("gussth").value = "";
            document.getElementById("nguss").value = "";
        };
        if (inputvalid) {
            var hp = Number(document.getElementById("mpower").value);
            var sg = Number(document.getElementById("slurrySG").value);
            var hsf = Number(document.getElementById("HSF").value);
            var tf = Number(document.getElementById("TF").value);
            var shdia = Number(document.getElementById("shdia").value);
            var hubdia = Number(document.getElementById("hubdia").value);
            var imptype = document.getElementById("ImpellerType").value;
            var pdia = Number(document.getElementById("pdia").value);
            var n = Number(document.getElementById("n").value);
            var contype = document.getElementById("ConnectionType").value;
            var earth = Number(document.getElementById("earth").value);
            var bladeth = Number(document.getElementById("bladeth").value);
            var nguss = Number(document.getElementById("nguss").value);
            var gussth = Number(document.getElementById("gussth").value);
            var pguss = "";
            var earlen = 0;
            switch(imptype) {
                case "3300":
                    var bladeang = 45;
                    var nblades = 3;
                    var npo = 0.3;
                    var c = 0.6;
                    var bladefac = 0.16;
                    if (bolted) {
                        if (pdia >= 90) {
                            var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia / 11 + .49) / 2;
                        } else {
                            var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia / 12 + .49) / 2;
                        }
                        hubear = hubdia * .85 / Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
                        if (hubear < earwdth) {
                            earwdth2 = hubear;
                        } else {
                            earwdth2 = earwdth;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "3400":
                    var bladeang = 45;
                    var nblades = 4;
                    var npo = 0.37;
                    var c = 0.7;
                    var bladefac = 0.16;
                    if (bolted) {
                        if (pdia >= 90) {
                            var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia / 11 + .49) / 2;
                        } else {
                            var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia / 12 + .49) / 2;
                        }
                        hubear = hubdia * .85 / Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
                        if (hubear < earwdth) {
                            earwdth2 = hubear;
                        } else {
                            earwdth2 = earwdth;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "4445":
                    var bladeang = 45;
                    var nblades = 4;
                    var npo = 1.27;
                    var c = 1.2107;
                    var bladefac = 0.19;
                    if (bolted) {
                        var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia * 0.095 + .49) / 2;
                        hubear = hubdia * .85 / Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
                        if (hubear < earwdth) {
                            earwdth2 = hubear;
                        } else {
                            earwdth2 = earwdth;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "4490":
                    var bladeang = 90;
                    var nblades = 4;
                    var npo = 3.64;
                    var c = 1.97;
                    var bladefac = 0.19;
                    if (bolted) {
                        var earwdth = Math.round(2 * pdia * 0.095 + .49) / 2;
                        hubear = hubdia * .85 / Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
                        if (hubear < earwdth) {
                            earwdth2 = hubear;
                        } else {
                            earwdth2 = earwdth;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            var bladewdth = bladefac * pdia;
            if (bolted) {
                earlen = earwdth + earth + .125;
            }
            var Fa = 0.97 * sg * c * Math.pow((n / 60), 2) * Math.pow((pdia / 12), 4) / nblades;
            var Ft = 0.7705 * sg * npo * tf * Math.pow((n / 60), 2) * Math.pow((pdia / 12), 4) / nblades;
            var Fra = Fa * Math.cos(bladeang * Math.PI / 180) + Ft * Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
            var Fr = (0.8 + 0.2 * hsf) * Fra;
            var Mblade = Fr * (0.4 * pdia - 0.5 * hubdia - earlen);
            if (bolted) {
                var Mear = Fr * (0.4 * pdia - 0.5 * hubdia);
                var bladestress = 6 * Mblade / (bladewdth * Math.pow(bladeth, 2));
                if (gusset) {
                    var gussht = Math.round(4 * pdia / 32 + .49) / 4;
                    var NAxis = (((earth / 2) * earwdth * earth) + ((earth + (gussht / 2)) * gussht * gussth * nguss)) / (earth * earwdth + gussht * gussth * nguss);
                    var MInert = (((1 / 12) * earwdth * Math.pow(earth, 3)) + (earwdth * earth * Math.pow((NAxis - (earth / 2)), 2))) + ((1 / 12) * nguss * gussth * Math.pow(gussht, 3)) + (nguss * gussth * gussht * Math.pow((NAxis - (earth + (gussht / 2))), 2));
                    var earstress = Mear * (earth + gussht - NAxis) / MInert;
                    pguss = "with Gusset(s)";
                } else {
                    var NAxis = earth/2;
                    var MInert = ((1 / 12) * earwdth * Math.pow(earth, 3));
                    var earstress = Mear * (earth - NAxis) / MInert;
                }
            } else {            
                var NAxis = bladeth/2;
                var hubear = hubdia * .85 / Math.sin(bladeang * Math.PI / 180);
                if (hubear < bladewdth) {
                    var earwdth2 = hubear;
                } else {
                    var earwdth2 = bladewdth;
                }
                var MInert = ((1 / 12) * earwdth2 * (bladeth ^ 3));
                var bladestress = 6 * Mblade / (earwdth2 * Math.pow(bladeth, 2));
            }
            var PD = (npo * sg * tf * Math.pow((n / 60), 3) * Math.pow((pdia * 25.4 / 1000), 5)) / 0.746;
            document.getElementById("stresstitle").innerHTML = contype + " Blade MP-"+imptype+ " Impeller "+pguss;
            if (bolted) {
                document.getElementById("earstress1").innerHTML = "\u03C3, Ear-root (psi)";
                document.getElementById("earstress2").innerHTML = earstress.toFixed(2);
            }
            document.getElementById("bladestress1").innerHTML = "\u03C3, Blade at ear tip       (psi)";
            document.getElementById("bladestress2").innerHTML = bladestress.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("powerdraw1").innerHTML = " Impeller Power Draw        (hp)";
            document.getElementById("powerdraw2").innerHTML = PD.toFixed(2);
            if (bolted) {
                if (earwdth > earwdth2) {
                    document.getElementById("taper").innerHTML = "Note: Ear Width tapered at hub weld from "+earwdth+" to "+earwdth2;
                }
            } else {
                if (bladewdth > earwdth2) {
                    document.getElementById("taper").innerHTML = "Note: Blader Width tapered at hub weld from "+bladewdth+" to "+earwdth2;
                }
            }
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a lot of code.  Can you narrow it down?

Comment: some people like to see code.  It has to do with when the button is pressed sometimes it refreshes sometimes it doesn't.  I think UraniumSteele may be onto something with the form tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `<form>` tag which when a button is clicked causes the brower to refresh.  If you are running this as a local file, that is file://mytest.html  instead of having it delivered by a server then change the `<form>` tag to something like a `<div>`.

Comment: Yes this worked now I have the autofill to figure out the form was allowing me to not have the popup of suggestions.

Comment: okay it was autocomplete="off" and it works on form tags and input tags so I added to all input tags.